# geocode reverse callback function not called

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm new to Javascript.  I'm trying to use Google api's Gmap v3 to realize a reverse geocodification. I've read many tutorials and wrote a simple code. The problem is that the anonymous function passed to geocoder.geocode() sometimes works but sometimes it doesn't. Thanks for your help!.

```
    function geoCode(latStr,lngStr){


      var lat = parseFloat(latStr);
      var lng = parseFloat(lngStr);
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    codeLatLng(latlng,function(addr){
      alert(addr); // sometimes message appears.
    });
     }


  function codeLatLng(latlng,callback) {
      if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              callback(results[1].formatted_address);
            } else {
              alert("No results found");
            }
          } else {
            alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes works but sometimes doesn't"?  Where are you using it when that occurs?  Do you get the other alerts?

Comment: I mean, I don't get any other alert... the anonymous function it's not called sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the Google service would return `null` or an empty array, but to be safe you could check both using: `if (results && results.length > )`.  Also, are you forgetting that arrays in Javascript are zero-based?  You probably want `results[0]`:

```
if (results && results.length > 0) {
    callback(results[0].formatted_address);
} else {
    alert("No results found");
}
```

By way of explanation: your code would crash on `if (results[1])`, in cases where "results" is an array of length 0 or 1, hence I'm guessing the intermittent failure.

Comment: You are right, are zero based. I code it based on an example and that example did results[1]. I'll try using [0]... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng' : position
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    address = results[1].formatted_address;
                    // alert("Wow ! Got it");
                } else {
                    // alert("No results
                    // found");
                    infowindow.setContent("No address found");
                }
            } else {
                // alert("Geocoder failed due
                // to: " + status);
                infowindow.setContent("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
            infowindow.setContent(address + '<br/>' + Timestamp);
        });

        infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker, this);
        currentInfoWindow = infowindow;

    });
}
```

once try with the above code

Comment: What its infowindow? I'm not using google maps to show a map. I'm Using OpenLayers I just want use google for reverse geocoding. Thanks for your help.